# Is it possible to dynamically load directives in a template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making a widget system and I plan to have each widget be it's own directive. I want to be able to pass the directives that should be used from my controller to my view via an array.
This is what my code currently looks like:

```
app.controller('showDashboard', function ($scope){
   $scope.widgets = ['widget1', 'widget2', 'widget3'];
});
```

In View:

```
<article ng-repeat="widget in widgets" class="widget">
    <div {{widget}}></div>
</article>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('widget1', function (){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        templateUrl: 'testWidget.html'
    };
}).directive('widget2', function (){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        templateUrl: 'testWidget.html'
    };
}).directive('widget3', function (){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        templateUrl: 'testWidget.html'
    };
});
```

Comment: Yes, it didn't work. See code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be improved but just to get the idea

```
//html
<div wrapper mydir="widget"></div>
//js
.directive('wrapper', function ($compile){
                return {
                    restrict: "A",
                    scope: {
                        mydir: "="
                    },
                    link: function ( scope, element ) {
                        var html = '<test '+scope.mydir+'></test>';
                        var compiled = $compile( html )( scope );
                        element.append(compiled);
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: scope.mydir is returning undefined, and not "widget" I also tried changing scope to $scope, same error.

Comment: So I console.log(scope.mydir) inside the link function. It returns undefined. If I change scope to foo, and then console.log(foo.mydir) it works.

Edit: And now I just changed it back to scope and it works, lol, but thank you. I think this is a more direct answer to the original question.

Answer (score 4):

So rather than make the directive itself the widget, why not use `ng-include` to load in the templates which can themselves contain directives, controllers etc...

```
app.controller('showDashboard', function ($scope){
   $scope.widgets = ['widget1.html', 'widget2.html', 'widget3.html'];
});

<article ng-repeat="widget in widgets" class="widget">
    <div ng-include="widget"></div>
</article>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle with an example](http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/ZKGe2/).

And here is an updated fiddle that shows a [slightly more complex widget with a controller](http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/ZKGe2/1/).

Comment: @Kolby - No problem, I also included another example with a widget that has a controller so you can see how that all works.

Comment: @Josh - I'm only have one problem getting it working now. My templates are separate html pages, while yours are script tags with an ID. I'm not seeing the correlation, or how I would separate it out to it's own page.

Comment: @Kolby - You just need to reference the full URL. I only included the script tags for demo purposes. If you use a root relative path, then `ng-include` will pull them down just fine. Something like `/templates/mytemplate.html`